# How to exit / return from class as null

Tags: javascript, class, null, exit, terminate

Usually in other languages it would looks like NullReferenceException, but I don't know how to do this in js, actually I am beginner with knowledge of C# - not JS

```
<script>
    var x = new fooClass(null);

    function fooClass(foo)
    {
        if(foo===null)
            return;     // The return type is "fooClass"
                        // I want to return something that will tell that the
                        // class were wrong initialized, maybe exception?

        alert(foo); // show that the script continues
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Exactly. You can throw an exception stating the error message

```
if(foo === null)
   throw "null not allowed" // throw an exception with a message
```

[More about `throw` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

Comment: This will actually stop executing JS on whole page as I see it, I am trying now with try catch :) It's my fault in forming question

Comment: Always [throw an `Error`](http://www.devthought.com/2011/12/22/a-string-is-not-an-error/)!